# Can I transfer 100 PDFs files from Windows to Acrobat Reader on iPad without going through iTunes?

Tags: pdf, file-transfer

Can I transfer 100 PDFs files from Windows to Acrobat Reader on iPad without going through iTunes or transferring the file one by one?

Answer (score 3):

Provided you have space on your iCloud Drive, you could upload files via a browser on Windows to [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/#iclouddrive), then download those files/folder to your iPad using the "more locations" function in Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Other services like Dropbox, OneDrive, and Google Drive should be supported as other locations in the file browser.

[image]

If you want to copy these files from the Files app (from iCloud Drive, Dropbox, Google, etc.), you can navigate to the files, tap "Select", then tap the files you wish to transfer. Tap the folder icon at the bottom of the screen. Then select the path you wish to copy files to, which is On My iPad > Adobe Acrobat, then tap Copy. Do note that these files are copies and are not the originals. Any changes or notes you make on the copied files will only exist on your device and not on the cloud.

These screenshots show a basic outline of the instructions above.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, 1) can you use "more locations" for several files at once? 2) for services like Dropbox, OneDrive, and Google Drive in the file browser, can you make them accessible when offline?

Comment: I've added some additional instructions on how to get it saved locally in the Adobe Acrobat Reader app. This saves in the same place as the iTunes file transfer. Accessing files in More Locations doesn't save in-app, but in the Files file browser app. You can access different services' files offline if you have them saved offline in their respective apps. Use the above instructions to save the files locally into Acrobat Reader. Let me know if you have more questions.